# Un able to post data to database using Bootstrap modal pop up in asp.net web forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am using asp.net web forms and i want tom post data from the modal pop up to the database, this is not working, however is just put textboxes in the body of the content page its saving data just fine, i need to use modal pops as all the project i want to do requires this. my code is as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        insertkpi();
    });


    function insertkpi() {
        $('#savebtn').click(function () {
            var kpi = {};
            kpi.Name = $('#TextBox1').val();
            kpi.initiative = $('#TextBox2').val();
            kpi.perfomance = $('#TextBox3').val();
            kpi.progress = $('#TextBox4').val();
            kpi.BaseTarget = $('#TextBox5').val();
            kpi.streachTarget = $('#TextBox6').val();
            kpi.Period = $('#TextBox7').val();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'addKpi.aspx/submitkpi',
                method: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: '{item: ' + JSON.stringify(kpi) + '}',
                success: function () {
                    displayKPI();

                },

                error: function (xhr, status, p3, p4) {
                    console.debug(xhr);
                    var err = "Error " + " " + status + " " + p3;
                    if (xhr.responseText && xhr.responseText[0] == "{")
                        err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).message;
                    alert(err);
                }

            });
        });
    }


</script>
```

modal div

```
 <div class="modal" id="kpimodal" data-keyboad="false" data-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">New KPI</h4>
                <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="subdata">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label id ="namlb">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" runat="server" placeholder ="name" id="nametxt" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label id ="inlb">Initiative</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" runat="server" placeholder ="initiative" id="inittxt" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label id ="perflb">Perfomance</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" runat="server" placeholder ="perfomance" id="perftxt" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label id ="proglb">Progress</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" runat="server" placeholder ="progress" id="progtxt" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label id ="baselb">Base Target</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" runat="server" placeholder ="base Target" id="basetxt" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label id ="streachlb">Streach Target</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" runat="server" placeholder ="streach target" id="strtxt" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label id ="perlb">Target Period</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" runat="server" placeholder ="Period" id="periodtxt" />
                </div>

                </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn-primary" runat="server" id="savebtn">Save</button>
                <button class="btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Enter New KPI

the webmethod in the web service

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static string submitkpi(insertkpi item)
    {
        string constring = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constring))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO KPIs (Name,Initiative,perfomance,progress,BaseTarget,streachTarget,Period) Values(@Name,@Initiative,@perfomance,@progress,@BaseTarget,@streachTarget,@Period)", conn))
            {
                try
                {
                conn.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", item.Name);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Initiative", item.Initiative);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@perfomance", item.perfomance);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@progress", item.progress);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BaseTarget", item.BaseTarget);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@streachTarget", item.streachTarget);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Period", item.Period);


                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception )
                {

                }
                finally
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your kpi object you have `kpi.name set = $("#Textbox1").val()`. However, this doesn't exist in your modal. For your name text box in your modal the ID is nametxt. So use `kpi.name = $("#nametxt").val();` to create your object.

Comment: hi Colby Boren, kpi.name = $("#nametxt").val(); corrected but still not working

Comment: @Timothy Ok. Have you tried console.log() on the kpi object to see if it is being creating correctly?

Comment: i really dont know how to do that, but the issue is that its only not working when using a modal dialog. when using textbox and buttons on in the body its working

Comment: i am getting 500 internal server error, how do i solve this

Answer (score 0):

the JSON.stringfy does not seem ok  to me you would get invalid json try like this

```
 $.ajax({
            url: 'addKpi.aspx/submitkpi',
            method: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data:  JSON.stringify({item:kpi}),
            success: function () {
                displayKPI();

            },
```

Comment: Hi @Ivan Stefner,

Comment: i have changed the JSON.stringfy but still not working. posting to the database is working if im not using bootstrap modal pop up, however i want to use a modal pop up, so i suspect that the problem is with the modal, but i cant see where exactly

Comment: Hi @Timothy do you get an error in your code, or an exception, what does the browser console say?

Comment: hi @Ivan Stefner im getting 401 Unauthorized

Comment: That means that the client can't be authorized, i don't think that the code i bad. Try editing your your yor web.config add this

<authorization>
        <allow users="*" /> 
 </authorization>

Comment: hi added that in web.config now im getting this error

Comment: HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Comment: in web.config inside the <configuration> tag insert this
<location path="Page.aspx">//your page name where the web service is 
<system.web>
<authorization>
<allow users="*"/> // this will allow access to everyone to register.aspx

</authorization>
</system.web>

</location>

Comment: now im getting 500 internal server error, im using the webservice.asmx unlike rhe aspx page

Comment: ok try this 
<location path="SecuredMethod.asmx">
  <system.web>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
  </system.web>
</location>